# Xcode 10 with iOS 14 device - An error was encountered while attempting to communicate with this device. (The service is invalid.)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10, ios14

Is there any solution to fix this error?

My project is not working in Xcode 11/12 as one of our third party framework is not being supported. I have been copying DeviceSupport for my Xcode 10 since last year from Xcode 11 and all along it was working fine.
[image: Xcode 10.3 support folder]

Ever since upgrading my iPad to iOS 14, it is showing me this new error:
[image: Xcode 10.3 error when run]
Obviously I have tried to reconnect the device, restart, and tried to search for solution in forums.

Please share if you have run into this problem too.

- iOS 13 is still working fine with my Xcode 10.3, and I am able to run my project in simulator as well.

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @JackChen nope, I can only debug on my Simulator. Even though it shows this error message, the app is still updated on my iPad though.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for this problem. Build (Command + B) using Xcode 11 and Deploy or Run Without Building (Option + Command + R) using Xcode 12 and it deploys to device successfully and debugger is also attached. However, for some reason debugger is not working as expected for me using this approach.